# CakePHP2.0 How to use a function within a component?

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

This might be a very noob question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. Is it possible to make your own function in a component and call it in the same component?

Example:

```
Class myComponent extends Component{

 public function doSomething(){

  doThis();

  $b = $a + 2;

  return $b;

 }

 function doThis(){

  $a = 0;

 }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up several things here.

1. You can generally create ***object methods*** like this without problem. You have to call them as objects methods though:

   ```
   public function doSomething() {
       $this->doThis();
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Just calling `doThis()` won't magically create the variable `$a` in the calling scope. The variable will be created inside `doThis` and will be contained there. And that's a good thing. You'll have to explicitly `return` the value from the method to make it available:

   ```
   public function doSomething() {
       $a = $this->doThis();
       ...
   }

   protected function doThis() {
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Time to edit the question and post a great answer? Goodness me, that deserves a +1!

Comment: Thanks!! This is the explanation I needed. Got my problem solved using what you just explained.

Answer (score 0):

Variable scope would mean that the `$a` inside the `doThis` function is lost when the function finishes, but you could do this:

```
Class myComponent extends Component
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        $a=$this->doThis();
        $b = $a + 2;
        return $b;
    }

    function doThis()
    {
        $a = 0;
        return $a;
    }

}
```

I would probably use a class property like this though:

```
Class myComponent extends Component
{
    public $a;
    public function doSomething()
    {
        $this->doThis();
        $b = $this_.a + 2;
        return $b;
    }

    public function doThis()
    {
        $this->a = 0;
    }

}
```

Class properties are a great way to update information through a function. They are accessible to the entire class anywhere. If you declare it via `public` if can be used outside the class directly via the instance like this:

```
$var=new myComponent();
// Crete a new instance of the object.
echo $var->a; // Outputs the value.
```

Alternately you can use `private` properties which are visible to the object itself within the functions, but invisible to the outside world (well, not accessible anyhow).